# chrome work normal but firefox get me this erorr

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-chrome, firefox

webdriver.firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in 
webdriver.firefox()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a typo.

```
webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: the problem with"F"  thanks broo

Comment: Note the capital F.

in selenium you should use capital webdriver.Chrome() , webdriver.Firefox()